# Filtering on primary key with nullable column in cassandra versions 1.2.5 and greater

Tags: cassandra, cql

Im trying to understand how to do this, or if I cant, why cant I do this. ie

```
cqlsh:ps> create table s1 (a text, b text, stuff text, primary key(a,b));
cqlsh:ps> select * from s1 where a='a' and b=null;
Bad Request: Invalid null clustering key part b
```

It appears that there is a work around, i.e. don't store nulls in column "b", but something like "##null##", but that just seems silly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've shown your table structure and your read query, but if you could show the insert query it would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert a `null` into `b` because it's part of the clustering key. If you try an insert query along the lines of the below: 
`INSERT INTO ps.s1 (a, b, c) VALUES ('a', null, 'c_val');` 
You should get an exception:
`Bad Request: Invalid null value for clustering key part password`

If you want to retrieve all data where `a`=`a` then you would simply do:

```
select * from s1 where a='a';
```

You can however insert nulls into fields which aren't part of the key:

```
INSERT INTO ps.s1 (a, b, c) VALUES ('a', 'b', null);
```